# Creating multi-level dictionary from string [Python]

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm creating a mail "bot" for one of my web services that will periodically collect a queue of e-mail messages to be sent from a PHP script and send them via Google's SMTP servers. The PHP script returns the messages in this format:

```
test@example.com:Full Name:shortname\ntest2@example.com:Another Full Name:anothershortname\ntest@example.com:Foo:bar
```

I need to "convert" that into something like this:

```
{
    "test@example.com": [
        [
            "Full Name",
            "shortname"
        ],
        [
            "Foo",
            "bar"
        ]
    ],
    "test2@example.com": [
        [
            "Another Full Name",
            "anothershortname"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Notice I need to have only one key per e-mail, even if there are multiple instances of an address. I know I can probably do it with two consecutive loops, one to build the first level of the dictionary and the second to populate it, but there should be a way to do it in one shot. This is my code so far:

```
raw = "test@example.com:Full Name:shortname\ntest2@example.com:Another Full Name:anothershortname\ntest@example.com:Foo:bar"

print raw

newlines = raw.split("\n")

print newlines

merged = {}
for message in newlines:
    message = message.split(":")
    merged[message[0]].append([message[1], message[2]])

print merged
```

I'm getting a KeyError on the last line of the loop, which I take to mean the key has to exist before appending anything to it (appending to a nonexistent key will not create that key).

I'm new to Python and not really familiar with lists and dictionaries yet, so your help is much appreciated!

Comment: The structure you give isn't valid.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - As I said I'm not all that familiar with dictionaries and lists yet; that's more of a pseudo-structure (I think that's actually valid JSON). Just something for me to visualize.

Comment: Oddly enough, approximately 99% of all valid JSON is valid Python as well. (But that's not valid JSON either.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about the error. So you have to check if the key is present. `'key' in dict` returns `True` if `'key'` is found in `dict`, otherwise `False`. Implementing this, here's your full code (with the debugging print statements removed):

```
raw = "test@example.com:Full Name:shortname\ntest2@example.com:Another Full Name:anothershortname\ntest@example.com:Foo:bar"
newlines = raw.split("\n")
merged = {}
for message in newlines:
    message = message.split(":")
    if message[0] in merged:
        merged[message[0]].append([message[1], message[2]])
    else:
        merged[message[0]]=[[message[1], message[2]]]    
print merged
```

Notice the extra brackets for the nested list on the second last line.

Answer (score 1):

May work as:

```
for message in newlines:
    message = message.split(":")
    temp = []
    temp.append(message[1])
    temp.append(message[2])
    merged[message[0]] = temp
```

Actually maybe:

```
for message in newlines:
    message = message.split(":")
    temp = []
    temp.append(message[1])
    temp.append(message[2])
    if message[0] not in merged:
        merged[message[0]] = []
    merged[message[0]].append(temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you've already accepted an answer, but maybe you're anyhow interested that what you're doing can be easily achieved with [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
raw = "test@example.com:Full Name:shortname\ntest2@example.com:Another Full Name:anothershortname\ntest@example.com:Foo:bar"

merged = defaultdict(list)
for line in raw.split('\n'):
    line = line.split(':')
    merged[line[0]].append(line[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check for presence of key, if it is not present, create the key,
if it is present, then append the data to existing list.

```
if(messsage[0] in merged):
     merged[message[0]] = [message[1],[message[2]]
else:
     merged[message[0]].append([[message[1], message[2]])
```

Comment: Bracket mismatch. On the second line of code, that should be `[[message[1],message[2]]]`.